# cannot add multiple column with values in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to add the the data of reference to data, so I use

```
data[reference.columns]=reference
```

but it only creates the column with no value, how can I add the value?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can show what the output of `data.index` and `reference.index` are

Comment: I have updated the question@ALollz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two DataFrames are indexed differently, so when you do `data[reference.columns] = reference` it tries to align the new columns on indices. Since the indices of `reference` are not in `data` (or only align for `index=0`) it adds the columns, but fills the values with `NaN`.

It looks like you want to add multiple static columns to `data` with the values from `reference`. You can just assign these:

```
for col in reference.columns:
    data[col] = reference[col].values[0]
```

---

Here's an illustration of the issue.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'val1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
reference = pd.DataFrame({'id2': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'val2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
```

These have the same indices ranging from 0-3.

```
data[reference.columns] = reference
```

Outputs

```
   id val1  id2 val2
0   1    A    1    A
1   2    B    2    B
2   3    C    3    C
3   4    D    4    D
```

But, if these DataFrames have different indices (that only partially overlap):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'val1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
reference = pd.DataFrame({'id2': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'val2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
reference.index=[3,4,5,6]

data[reference.columns]=reference
```

Outputs:

```
   id val1  id2 val2
0   1    A  NaN  NaN
1   2    B  NaN  NaN
2   3    C  NaN  NaN
3   4    D  1.0    A
```

As only the index value of 3 is shared.